# Copy a basic_string<char16_t> to vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, char16-t

Please suggest an efficient way to copy bytes from a basic_string< char16_t> to vector< uint8_t>.

I am not concerned with the encoding, and just want to copy the bytes to the bytearray. It will later be interpreted with the correct encoding downstream.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want two ints in the vector for every char in the string?

Comment: Yes. My char is in UTF-16. So it is two bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option is to get the data pointer, cast it to your new type and assign it to your target vector:

```
std::basic_string<char16_t> src;

const uint8_t *begin = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(src.data());
const uint8_t *end = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t const*>(src.data() + src.size());
std::vector<uint8_t> dst(begin,end);
```

This is one of the few cases where `reinterpret_cast` is a perfectly valid choice. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) (highlights added by me):

> Unlike `static_cast`, but like `const_cast`, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression **as if it had the type `new_type`**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done it that way. But I was actually wondering if there is another way avoiding reinterpret_casts.

Comment: @SkypeMeSM I think in this case a reinterpret_cast is perfectly valid. After all, thats exactly what is done: an array of `char16_t` is bitwise interpreted as an array of `uint8_t`.